# How to get ANOVA table with robust standard errors?

Tags: r, anova, multiple-regression, heteroscedasticity, robust-standard-error

I am running a pooled OLS regression using the plm package in R. Though, my question is more about basic statistics, so I try posting it here first ;)

Since my regression results yield heteroskedastic residuals I would like to try using heteroskedasticity robust standard errors. As a result from `coeftest(mod, vcov.=vcovHC(mod, type="HC0"))` I get a table containing estimates, standard errors, t-values and p-values for each independent variable, which basically are my "robust" regression results.

For discussing the importance of different variables I would like to plot the share of variance explained by each independent variable, so I need the respective sum of squares. However, using function `aov()`, I don't know how to tell R to use robust standard errors.

Now my question is: How do I get the ANOVA table/sum of squares that refers to robust standard errors? Is it possible to calculate it based on the ANOVA table from regression with normal standard errors?

Edit:

In other words and disregarding my R-issues:

If R$^2$ is not affected by using robust standard errors, will also the respective contributions to explained variance by the different explanatory variables be unchanged?

Edit:

In R, does `aov(mod)` actually give a correct ANOVA table for a panelmodel (plm)?

Answer (score 14):

The ANOVA in linear regression models is equivalent to the Wald test (and the likelihood ratio test) of the corresponding nested models. So when you want to conduct the corresponding test using heteroskedasticity-consistent (HC) standard errors, this cannot be obtained from a decomposition of the sums of squares but you can carry out the Wald test using a HC covariance estimate. This idea is used in both `Anova()` and `linearHypothesis()` from the `car` package and `coeftest()` and `waldtest()` from the `lmtest` package. The latter three can also be used with `plm` objects.

A simple (albeit not very interesting/meaningful) example is the following. We use the standard model from the `?plm` manual page and want to carry out a Wald test for the significance of both `log(pcap)` and `unemp`. We need these packages:

```
library("plm")
library("sandwich")
library("car")
library("lmtest")
```

The model (under the alternative) is:

```
data("Produc", package = "plm")
mod <- plm(log(gsp) ~ log(pc) + log(emp) + log(pcap) + unemp,
  data = Produc, index = c("state", "year"))
```

First, let's look at the marginal Wald tests with HC standard errors for all individual coefficients:

```
coeftest(mod, vcov = vcovHC)

t test of coefficients:

            Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
log(pc)    0.2920069  0.0617425  4.7294 2.681e-06 ***
log(emp)   0.7681595  0.0816652  9.4062 < 2.2e-16 ***
log(pcap) -0.0261497  0.0603262 -0.4335   0.66480    
unemp     -0.0052977  0.0024958 -2.1226   0.03411 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

And then we carry out a Wald test for both `log(pcap)` and `unemp`:

```
linearHypothesis(mod, c("log(pcap)", "unemp"), vcov = vcovHC)

Linear hypothesis test

Hypothesis:
log(pcap) = 0
unemp = 0

Model 1: restricted model
Model 2: log(gsp) ~ log(pc) + log(emp) + log(pcap) + unemp

Note: Coefficient covariance matrix supplied.

  Res.Df Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)  
1    766                       
2    764  2 7.2934    0.02608 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

Alternatively, we can also fit the model under the null hypothesis (`mod0` say) without the two coefficients and then call `waldtest()`:

```
mod0 <- plm(log(gsp) ~ log(pc) + log(emp),
  data = Produc, index = c("state", "year"))
waldtest(mod0, mod, vcov = vcovHC)

Wald test

Model 1: log(gsp) ~ log(pc) + log(emp)
Model 2: log(gsp) ~ log(pc) + log(emp) + log(pcap) + unemp
  Res.Df Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)  
1    766                       
2    764  2 7.2934    0.02608 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

The test statistic and p-value computed by `linearHypothesis()` and `waldtest()` is exactly the same. Just the interface and output formatting is somewhat different. In some cases one or the other is simpler or more intuitive.

Note: If you supply a covariance matrix estimate (i.e., a matrix like `vocvHC(mod)`) instead of a covariance matrix estimator (i.e., a function like `vocvHC`), make sure that you supply the HC covariance matrix estimate of the model under the alternative, i.e., the non-restricted model.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the Wald-test shows whether including certain variables is significant or not. But is there a measure of _how much_ they actually improve the model, as e.g. sum of squares?

Comment: How can I implement HAC standard errors? I tried coeftest(mod, vcov = vcovHAC) but got an error message saying "no applicable method for 'estfun' applied to an object of class "c('plm', 'panelmodel')". It seems I need to calculate weights or an estimation function first. What method would you recommend?

Comment: While the `plm` package has methods for the `vcovHC()` generic from the `sandwich` package, it does not provide methods for `vcovHAC()`. Instead `plm` ships with its own dedicated functions for computing covariance matrices in panel models that potentially include serial correlation as well. See `vcovNW()` or `vcovSCC()` in package `plm`.

Comment: Thank you! As far as I understand both functions relate to autocorrelation-robust SE. Is there any function that can be used for both heteroscedasticity- and autocorrelation-robust SE?

Comment: All three functions (`vcovHAC`, `vcovNW`, `vcovSCC`) are _H_eteroskedasticity and _A_utocorrelation _C_onsistent...that's what HAC stands for.

Comment: OK. In the plm description it sounded like they were only correcting for autocorrelation, since it said nothing about heteroskedasticity. coeftest(mod, vcov = vcovNW) gives the error message "object 'vcovNW' not found", although all packages are loaded. Also the example in the plm-package description gives the same error. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to check the corresponding papers which types of correlation and/or heteroskedasticity are exactly accounted for and which are not. There are more possible patterns in panel data than in cross-section data - and the details differ between the different estimators. And `vcovNW` was added in recent versions of `plm` (1.5-x).

Comment: Will this approach work with `mlm` objects from multivariate regressions?

Comment: Conceptually, the same strategy could be employed: `vcovHC()` works for `mlm` objects and the same idea for the Wald test can be employed. However, because in `mlm` the `coef()` are stored as a matrix as opposed to a vector with the same naming convention as the `vcov()`, the `waldtest()` function does not work out of the box. It might be possible to write a `waldtest.mlm()` method that uses the same trick as the `coeftest.mlm()` method (computing the vcov first, replacing the coef matrix with a vector, and then calling the default method) but I would need to have a closer look at this...

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with the `Anova` function in the `car` package. See [this excellent answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/91881/36229) for more detail and a review of other techniques for dealing with heteroskedasticity in ANOVA.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is, that Anova() does not seem to work with models of type plm (panelmodel).

Comment: @Aki if I'm not mistaken the pooled OLS is equivalent to plain OLS, based on what it says in the vignette: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/vignettes/plm.pdf

Comment: @Aki however it sounds like you might be interested in a richer ANOVA model. There are some R examples here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3874/unbalanced-mixed-effect-anova-for-repeated-measures